# Create Pandas Holiday for SIFMA Good Friday

Tags: python, pandas

For SIFMA (bonds) market, Good Friday is NOT a holiday if it is the first Friday of the month because NFP (Non-Farm Payroll) numbers coming out.

We can use a hack to take the existing holidays and not include them if day of month <= 7, but this is ugly.  Is there a way to properly define rules where the NFP Fridays are taken into account?

This works, but is ugly:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import (
    AbstractHolidayCalendar,
    Holiday,
    nearest_workday,
    sunday_to_monday,
    GoodFriday,
)


# occurs on the first Friday of every month
sifma_good_friday_holidays = [
    Holiday('Good Friday', year=d.year, month=d.month, day=d.day)
    for d in GoodFriday.dates('1900-01-01', '2200-12-31')
    if d.day > 7
]
```

**Note** You cannot currently create a holiday where you both pass in an offset and an observance (so you can't simply add an observance that filters out the holidays where the day of the month <= 7)

The following does seem to work, but also seems like quite a kludge.

```
def not_NFP_GoodFriday(dt: datetime):
     possible = GoodFriday.dates(date(dt.year,1,1), date(dt.year,12,31))[0]
     if possible.day <= 7:
           return None
     return datetime.fromtimestamp(possible.timestamp())

sifma_good_friday_holidays = Holiday("NFP Good Friday", month=1, day=1, 
                                     observance=not_NFP_GoodFriday)
```

Is there no better way than one of these two functions?

Comment: Is it possible to extract the data until the 7th of the month and that day is a Friday? `sifma_good_friday_holidays = [
    Holiday('Good Friday', year=d.year, month=d.month, day=d.day)
    for d in GoodFriday.dates('1900-01-01', '2200-12-31')
    if (d.day < 7) and (d.weekday() == 4)
]`

Comment: @r-beginners: Good Friday  is always a Friday, so weekday part doesn't add anything.

Both code blocks above work, they just both seem like hacks. I'm hoping there is a better way out there.